# HTTP post returns 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: vue.js, axios, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to save data using Axios API from my front end which is built using the Quasar framework. When I am sending the API request it is responding 400 (Bad Request). SO far what have tried is given in below. I am new to this Framework. So if anyone can help me with this and suggest any good tutorial for learning Quasar then it will be much more helpful for me.

```
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div class="row q-col-gutter-sm q-ma-xs q-mr-sm">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <q-card
          flat
          bordered
          class
        >
          <q-card-section>
            <div class="text-h6">Add Style Status</div>
          </q-card-section>

          <q-separator inset></q-separator>
          <q-card-section>
            <q-form>
              <q-list>
                <!-- <q-item>
                  <q-item-section>
                    <q-input
                      dense
                      outlined
                      v-model="styleStatus.styleStatusId"
                      label="Style Status Id"
                    />
                  </q-item-section>
                </q-item> -->

                <q-item>
                  <q-item-section>
                    <q-input
                      dense
                      outlined
                      v-model="styleStatus.statusName"
                      label="Style Status Name"
                    />
                  </q-item-section>
                </q-item>

              <q-card-actions
                align="right"
                class="text-teal"
              >
                <q-btn
                :label="styleStatus.styleStatusId==='' ? 'Save' : 'Update' "
                  type="submit"
                  color="positive"
                  v-close-popup
                  :disabled="!styleStatus.statusName"
                  icon-right="save"
                  @click="addNewStyleStatus()"
                />
              </q-card-actions>
              </q-list>
            </q-form>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      filter: '',
      mode: 'list',
      styleStatus: {
        styleStatusId: '',
        statusName: ''
      },
      pagination: {
        rowsPerPage: 10
      },
      model: null,
      data: this.data
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNewStyleStatus () {
      if (this.styleStatus.styleStatusId !== '') {
        this.updateData()
      } else {
        this.saveData()
      }
    },
    saveData () {
      this.$axios.post('http://192.168.0.11:8020/api/StyleStatuses', this.styleStatus)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          this.$q.notify({
            color: 'positive',
            position: 'top-right',
            message: 'Record Inserted Successfully',
            icon: 'check_circle'
          })
          this.getAllStyleStatus()
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$q.notify({
            color: 'negative',
            position: 'top-right',
            message: 'Oooops!! something was wrong.',
            icon: 'report_problem'
          })
        })
    },
    updateData () {
      this.$axios.put('http://192.168.0.11:8020/api/StyleStatuses/', this.styleStatus)
        .then(res => {
          this.$q.notify({
            color: 'positive',
            position: 'top-right',
            message: 'Record Updated Successfully',
            icon: 'check_circle'
          })
          this.styleStatus = {}
          this.getAllStyleStatus()
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.$q.notify({
            color: 'negative',
            position: 'top-right',
            message: 'Oooops!! something was wrong.',
            icon: 'report_problem'
          })
        })
    },
    editData (x) {
      this.styleStatus = x.row
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Have you checked the [video tutorials](https://quasar.dev/video-tutorials)? Quasar will not help you with a malformed request, though. You can find the error message in the network tab of your browser's dev-tools

Comment: Yes, I have checked the video tutorials. This API worked fine when my primary key was in int, or string. When I have hanged the Primary key to System.Guid then this error is coming.

Comment: Well then it seems the backend does not accept the guid value. This has likely nothing to do with Quasar. Can you share code for the controller and request validation?

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved. The error was coming from the backend as the GUID value doesn't support empty string. So, after I removed the column form the object which I was passing from the front end the error was solved.